# an easy algebra question

Tags: extension-field, minimal-polynomials

$\mathbb{K}$ is a field extension of field $\mathbb{F}$ and $a\in \mathbb{K}$ and if $p(x) = min (\mathbb{F},a)$,
why $\mathbb{F}[x]/(p(x))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}[a]$?

Comment: There are some things wrong here. $F[a] = F$ since $a\in F$.

Comment: sorry, I edited that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\phi:\mathbb{F}[X]\to \mathbb{K}$ defined by $\phi(P)=P(a)$. This ring homomorphism has by definition of $\mathbb{F}[a]$ as range. Its kernel is by definition the ideal generated by the minimal polynomial. Whence the isomorphism.

Comment: very much thanks, that helped me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: The last sentence appears to be incomplete.

Comment: In French you would say : "d'où l'isomorphisme"

Comment: A literal translation of "d'où" is "whence", whence my edit.

Comment: Thank you, your English is better than mine